# TIN to Raster - specify raster's origin

Tags: arcpy, dem, 3d-analyst, tin

How could I specify raster's origin, while using arcpy.TinRaster_3d?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Could you please edit your question to include as much relevant information as possible (eg. explain what you already tried, what problems you experienced etc)

Comment: [Arc's help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00q900000077000000) says "you can specify the output raster's origin, extent, and resolution or cell spacing to create a raster covering only a portion of the TIN" but fails to say _how_ to specify any of those besides resolution.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the origin as the Xmin, Ymin (or Left & Bottom) of the extent environment setting. Click the Environment button at the bottom of the tool's interface, click Processing Extent and fill in the extent properties. You have to indicate Xmax & Ymax (Right, Top) as well:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to match an existing raster in ArcPy you set the [extent](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w00000009000000) to that raster and it's also a good idea to set the [snapRaster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Snap_Raster/001w0000000m000000/) as well:

```
import arcpy

InRaster = "c:\\some\\path\\to\\raster.tif"

DescObj = arcpy.Describe(InRaster)
arcpy.env.extent = DescObj.extent # match the extent of the input raster
arcpy.env.snapRaster = InRaster   # match the edges of the raster
```

Note that this method of setting the extent works with any feature or raster data but the value of the snap raster must be a raster.

Extents of data can include a healthy buffer around the data so setting the output extent alone is good but specifying a snap raster is better!

The [snapRaster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Snap_Raster/001w0000000m000000/) ensures that the cells of the raster align at the origin; if the cell size is the same then the rasters will perfectly overlay. When using snapRaster you will get the most use if the raster to be produced is either the same, a factor of or a multiple of the snap rasters' cell size.